# Type '{}' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

I am using ramda's `toPairs` functions.

```
import { toPairs } from 'ramda';

renderMenuItems({ copy, remove, add, update }) {
    return (
      toPairs({ copy, remove, add, update })
        // make sure we have a function first.
        .filter(([, val]) => typeof val === 'function')
        .map(([key, value], idx) =>
          <MenuItem
            key={idx}
            icon={ICONS[key]} //Error: Type '{}' cannot be used as an index type
            caption={CAPTIONS[key]}
            onClick={() => value()}
          />,
      )
    );
  }
```

The `key` and `value` is in type `{}`. But as per docs(http://ramdajs.com/docs/#toPairs) it is a string.
Can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: What is the definition of `renderMenuItems`?

Comment: Its function name.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(key);` to see what exactly is the `key`?

Comment: @NelsonYeung its string value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to helping me.

I am able to solve the issue by setting the type of `key` and `value` of object that I have passed to the function `toPairs`. I found it on Github doc for @types.ramda test cases (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ramda/ramda-tests.ts)

Here is the solution.

```
 return (
      toPairs<string, number>({ copy, remove, add, update })
      ...
```

It looks like the default type is `{}` for both the `key` and the `value`